# How to create order using REST API?

Tags: magento2, checkout, api, sales-order, rest-api

I need to use the Magento REST API to create an order from a mobile client. In my case, the mobile side will implement the payment directly using PayPal SDK. What I need to do is to create an order by setting the payment method to a money order and performing a guest checkout. Which API(s) should I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Here is what I'm doing.

### Get a single product

```
curl -g -X GET "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/products/24-MB05/" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

### Create cart

```
curl -g -X POST "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

### Get Cart

```
curl -g -X GET "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/56241bf6bc084cd7589426c8754fc9c5" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

### Add Product To Cart

```
curl -g -X POST "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/56241bf6bc084cd7589426c8754fc9c5/items" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \
 -d '{ "cartItem": { "quote_id": "56241bf6bc084cd7589426c8754fc9c5", "sku": "24-MB05", "qty": 1 } }'
```

### Add shipping information

```
curl -g -X POST "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/56241bf6bc084cd7589426c8754fc9c5/shipping-information" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '
{
    "addressInformation": {
        "shippingAddress": {
            "region": "MH",
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "Chakala,Kalyan (e)"
            ],
            "company": "abc",
            "telephone": "1111111",
            "postcode": "12223",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "firstname": "Sameer",
            "lastname": "Sawant",
            "email": "abc@abc.com",
            "prefix": "address_",
            "region_code": "MH",
            "sameAsBilling": 1
        },
        "billingAddress": {
            "region": "MH",
            "region_id": 0,
            "country_id": "IN",
            "street": [
                "Chakala,Kalyan (e)"
            ],
            "company": "abc",
            "telephone": "1111111",
            "postcode": "12223",
            "city": "Mumbai",
            "firstname": "Sameer",
            "lastname": "Sawant",
            "email": "abc@abc.com",
            "prefix": "address_",
            "region_code": "MH"
        },
        "shipping_method_code": "flatrate",
        "shipping_carrier_code": "flatrate"
    }
}
 '
```

### Get Payment Method

```
curl -g -X GET "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/56241bf6bc084cd7589426c8754fc9c5/payment-information" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

### Place Order

```
curl -g -X PUT "$base_url/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/56241bf6bc084cd7589426c8754fc9c5/order" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
    -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '
{
    "paymentMethod": {
        "method": "checkmo"
    }
}'
```

Comment: I created a sample php script based on your answer here, if someone wants to try this via php: https://github.com/acolono/php-magento-api-sandbox

Comment: @zzpaul, How to pass creditcard data using payflow method using above way?

Comment: Yes Helpful thanks

Comment: absolute legend, thanks for this amazing answer

Answer (score 7):

I think there is a little mistake: For placing order, on the body, it has to be paymentMethod the first key, like this:

```
{
    "paymentMethod": { 
        "method": "checkmo" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

1. create empty cart
   url : http://www.[yoursite].com/rest/V1/carts/mine
   call: post
   response: cartID eg: 4290
2. Add item to the cart
   url : http://www.[yoursite].com/rest/V1/carts/mine/items
   body:

   ```
   {"cartItem":{
       "sku":"JFCO00017",
       "qty":1,
       "name":"Devil May Cry III 3 Dante",
       "price":81.55,
       "product_type":"simple",
       "quote_id":"4290",
       "product_option":
           {"extension_attributes":
              {
                "custom_options":[
                 {"option_id":"thumbnail",
            "option_value":"\/d\/e\/devilmaycryiii3dantecosplay_1_.jpg"
              },
              {
                "option_id":"color_2",
                "option_value":"Red"
              },
              {
               "option_id":"google_size",
               "option_value":"xxs"}]
          }
       }
     }
   }
   ```
3. Add billling info
   url : http://www.[yoursite].com/rest/V1/carts/mine/billing-address
   body:

   ```
   {
   "address": {
   "city": "Springfield",
   "company": "iprag",
   "countryId": "IN",
   "email": "customer_email@domain.com",
   "firstname": "Jane",
   "lastname": "Doe",
   "postcode": "90210",
   "region": "UP",
   "saveInAddressBook": 1,
   "street": ["Street"],
   "telephone": "5551234"
   },
   "useForShipping": true
   }
   ```
4. get shipping-methods
   url : http://www.[yoursite].com/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-methods

   ```
   {
   "carrier_code": "flatrate",
   "method_code": "flatrate",
   "carrier_title": "Flat Rate",
   "method_title": "Fixed",
   "amount": 10,
   "base_amount": 10,
   "available": true,
   "error_message": "",
   "price_excl_tax": 10,
   "price_incl_tax": 10
   ```

   }
5. add shipping info
   url : http://www.[yoursite].com/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information
   body:

   ```
   {
    "addressInformation": {
    "billingAddress": {
       "city": "Springfield",
       "company": "iprag",
       "email": "customer_email@domain.com",
       "firstname": "Jane",
       "lastname": "Doe",
       "postcode": "335001",
       "region": "UP",
       "street": ["Street"],
       "telephone": "5551234"
   },
   "shippingAddress": {
       "city": "Springfield",
       "company": "iprag",
       "email": "customer_email@domain.com",
       "firstname": "Jane",
       "lastname": "Doe",
       "postcode": "335001",
       "region": "UP",
       "street": ["Street"],
       "telephone": "5551234"
     },
     "shippingCarrierCode": "flatrate",
     "shippingMethodCode": "flatrate"
   }
   }
   ```

response: payment method and cart detail

5. Order place
   URL : http://www.[yoursite].com/rest/V1/carts/mine/order
   body :

   ```
   {
    "paymentMethod":{"method":"checkmo"},
    "shippingMethod":
       {
         "method_code":"flatrate",

         "carrier_code":"flatrate",
         "additionalProperties":{}

       }

   }
   ```

response: orderid

Comment: How to pass creditcard data using payflow method using above way?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, there is a Magento rest api call to get all available payment method fetch the list and place the order replacing the above method.

Comment: can you look up and let me know for this, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188939/how-to-capture-creditcard-payment-using-sales-order-rest-api-magento-2

Comment: @paul

have you created an order using REST API with PayPal Pro and Express????

Comment: @KetanPanchal No

Answer (score 1):

### Complete Order Flow for Guest and LoggedIn Customer Using REST API

## **Guest**

**1. **Create Empty Cart****

```
 End Point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/guest-carts

 Method    = POST
 Output    = token(hFJ9dQO4nkyTwWJFoiAdk9Bp4SF9aJo7)
```

**2. Get Cart ID By Token**

```
 End Point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/guest-carts/(token)

 Method    = GET
 Output    = Cart Details
```

**3.Add Item to Cart**

```
 End Point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/guest-carts/(token)/items

 Method    = POST
 Body      = `{ "cartItem": {
                  "sku": "ABC1088",
                  "qty": 1,
                  "quote_id": "6261"
                 }
              }`
 Output    = Added Product Details
```

**4.Fetch Shipping Method Details**

```
End Point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/guest-carts/(token)/estimate-shipping-methods
Method    = POST
Body      = `{
             "address": {
             "region": "Dubai",
             "country_id": "AE",
             "street": [
                        "L-142, 5th Main Rd"
                       ],
              "postcode": "123456",
              "city": "Goa",
              "firstname": "First Name",
              "lastname": "Last",
              "customer_id": null,
              "email": "last@codilar.com",
              "telephone": "12345678",
              "same_as_billing": 1
             }
           }`
  OutPut  =  Added Shipping Methods
```

**5. Fetch Available Payment Methods**

```
End Point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/guest-carts/(token)/shipping-information
Method    = POST
Body      = `{
"addressInformation": {
    "shipping_address": {
        "region": "Dubai",
        "country_id": "AE",
        "street": [
            "L-142, 5th Main Rd"
        ],
        "postcode": "12345",
        "city": "Hsr Layout",
        "firstname": "First Name",
        "lastname": "Last",
        "customer_id": null,
        "email": "cool@.com",
        "telephone": "12345678"
    },
    "billing_address": {
        "region": "Dubai",
        "country_id": "AE",
        "street": [
            "L-142, 5th Main Rd"
        ],
        "postcode": "12345",
        "city": "Goa",
        "firstname": "First Name",
        "lastname": "Last",
        "customer_id": null,
        "email": "cool@.com",
        "telephone": "12345"
    },
    "shipping_carrier_code": "instore",
    "shipping_method_code": "pickup"
}}`
Output = Available Payment Methods
```

**6. Place Order**

```
  End Point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/guest-carts/(token)/payment-information
  Method    = GET
  Body      = `{
            "email": "cool@.com",
           "paymentMethod": {
           "method": "cashondelivery"
            },
            "billing_address": {
            "email": "cool@.com",
            "region": "Dubai",
            "region_id": 612,
            "region_code": "",
            "country_id": "AE",
            "street": [
            "123 Dublin street"
            ],
           "postcode": "1234",
           "city": "Goa",
           "telephone": "1234",
           "firstname": "First Name",
           "lastname": "Last"
           }
         }`
```

### **LoggedIn**

**1. Get Customer Token**

```
    End Point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/integration/customer/token
    Method    = POST
    Body      = `{
                  "username":"test@gmail.com", 
                  "password":"Test123@@"
                  }`
    Output    = Bearer Token
```

**2. Get Cart Details**

```
   End Point  = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/carts/mine
   Method     = GET
   Output     = cart details
```

**3. Add Product to Cart**

```
   End Point  = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/carts/mine/items
   Method     = POST
   Header     = Bearer Token = ( Pass token from step -1(logged-in))
   Body       = `{
                 "cartItem": {
                 "sku": "ABC1088",
                 "qty": 1,
                 "quote_id": "6255"
                 }
                }`
   Output     = Added Product Details
```

**4. Add Billing Address**

```
  End Point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/carts/mine/billing-address
  Method    = POST
  Header    = Bearer Token = ( Pass token from step -1(logged-in)
  Body      = `{
                "address": {
                "city": "Hsr Layout",
                "company": "Codilar",
                "countryId": "AE",
                "email": "cool@.com",
                "firstname": "First",
                "lastname": "Last",
                "postcode": "1234",
                "region": "Dubai",
                "saveInAddressBook": 1,
                "street": ["L-142, 5th Main Rd"],
                "telephone": "12345"
               },
                "useForShipping": true
               }`
   Output  = You will get added details
```

**5. Get Shipping methods**

```
    End point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-methods
    Method    = GET
    Header    = Bearer Token = ( Pass token from step -1(logged-in)
```

**6. Get Shipping Information**

```
    End point = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information
    Method    = POST
    Header    = Bearer Token = ( Pass token from step -1(logged-in))
    Body      = `{
"addressInformation": {
    "shipping_address": {
        "region": "Dubai",
        "country_id": "AE",
        "street": [
            "L-142, 5th Main Rd"
        ],
        "postcode": "560102",
        "city": "Hsr Layout",
        "firstname": "First Name",
        "lastname": "Last",
        "customer_id": null,
        "email": "cool@.com",
        "telephone": "1234567"
    },
    "billing_address": {
        "region": "Dubai",
        "country_id": "AE",
        "street": [
            "L-142, 5th Main Rd"
        ],
        "postcode": "1234",
        "city": "Goa",
        "firstname": "First Name",
        "lastname": "Das",
        "customer_id": null,
        "email": "cool@.com",
        "telephone": "1234"
    },
    "shipping_carrier_code": "instore",
    "shipping_method_code": "pickup"
}}`
```

**7. Plae Order**

```
   End Point  = http://magento.local/en-uae/rest/V1/carts/mine/order
   Method     = PUT
   Header     = Bearer Token = ( Pass token from step -1(logged-in)
   Body       = `{
                  "paymentMethod":{"method":"checkmo"},
                  "shippingMethod":
                 {
                   "method_code":"freeshipping",
                   "carrier_code":"freeshipping",
                   "additionalProperties":{},
                   "region_id":""
                  }}`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an **official tutorial** showing how to make an order through REST API: 
[Order processing tutorial for Magento 2.2](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/tutorials/orders/order-intro.html)

They included very detailed steps:

1. Configure the store
2. Get the admin token
3. Create a customer
4. Create a quote
5. Add items to the cart
6. Prepare for checkout
7. Create an order
8. Create an invoice
9. Create a shipment
10. Issue a partial refund

The tutorial included how to add different kinds of products, different shipping method and many other useful information with sample codes.