# Magento 2 Rest api to create a order

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, rest-api

I need to use the `Magento REST API` to create an order.Which API(s) should I use to achieve this Or what are the steps to be followed to create an order with complete billing,shipping,payment details?

Answer (score 0):

Find your solution here, I have posted an answer instead of posting the same thing I am sharing the link. Please upvote if you got your solution so that it might help other as well.

[Magento 2 - Create order using REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136028/magento-2-create-order-using-rest-api/156446#156446)