# Add order pragmatically REST API

Tags: magento2, orders, api, rest-api

I'm supposed to:

1. Receive payment tokenization from mobile.
2. Save tokenize for the customer.
3. Use tokenize to add an order.
4. Do payment process.

How can I achieve these steps?

Please help.

Comment: @Rafael, Do you have a solution?

Comment: No, but I guess that it will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136028/magento-2-create-order-using-rest-api