# Create Order via SOAP api

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2, magento2-api

[Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136028/magento-2-create-order-using-rest-api) I found the example shows how to create an order using REST api is there any example to do the same with SOAP api in Magento 2.

Any suggestions, please?