# how to add cutom price via rest api - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, rest-api, guest-checkout

I'm following this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136028/magento-2-create-order-using-rest-api) to create guest order. I'm trying to add product to cart with my custom price, but the order will take the actual product price.

> POST /V1/guest-carts/{cartId}/items

**Rest URL**

`http://host/index.php/rest/V1/guest-carts/67435a34ccb029c707adca60303849a2/items`

**Data**

```
{ "cartItem": { "quote_id": "67435a34ccb029c707adca60303849a2", "sku": "MAR-410303SA046YL", "price": 10 "qty": 1 } }
```

When I check the order, item price is not **10**.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd like to know this also.