# How to Place order for specific product id?

Tags: magento2, product, orders, controllers, place-order

This is my controller to add a specific product to the cart. It is working fine. Now I don't need to add in cart, but directly to place order using product id. My product id is 483. I need to place order this product and redirect to another page.

```
<?php

namespace Module\Name\Controller\Index;

class Places extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{



protected $formKey;   
protected $cart;
protected $product;
protected $_response;
protected $customerRepository;
protected $addressRepository;

public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
 \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
 \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository ,
 \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,


array $data = []) {
    $this->formKey = $formKey;
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->product = $product;  
     $this->_response = $response;
     $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
     $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
 { 

  $productId =483;
  $params = array(
                'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
                'product' => $productId, //product Id
                'qty'   =>1 
               //quantity of product                
            );              
    //Load the product based on productID   
    $_product = $this->product->load($productId);       
    $this->cart->addProduct($_product, $params);
    $this->cart->save();
    //$this->_response->setRedirect('magento')->sendResponse();

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is through API as it falls in line with magento 2's idea of service contracts -

You can find how to do it in this answer - [Magento 2 - Create order using REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136028/magento-2-create-order-using-rest-api)

Comment: this seems to look like entering variables manually?

Comment: you can call API in php using curl and pass the parameters dynamically.