# How to create new order with a Rest Api

Tags: magento2

How can I create a new order by using a `rest api`.
Can you provide `api` link for creating a new order also provide us the procedure to create new order using rest API.

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions have been asked in Magento SE many times. Please check below links to get the answer:

[Magento 2 - Create order using REST API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/136028/magento-2-create-order-using-rest-api)

or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770986/how-to-place-an-order-using-magento2-api

You can also take help of Magento's official documentation (Link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/order-tutorial/order-intro.html).

Please don't ask a new question always. First, check the on google or Magento SE for the similar questions.

Comment: but how to create an order without using quote /payment , but just direct using /rest/default/V1/orders