# Magento 2 Create order from admin user using rest API

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api, place-order, create-order

I want to create orders from admin on behalf of a customer by using REST API. I have created cart and added items by using the below code.

```
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");
$baseUrl = 'http://test.com/';

$ch = curl_init($baseUrl."rest/V1/integration/admin/token");


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);


/* Create empty cart for the guest customer  */
$ch =  curl_init($baseUrl."rest/V1/guest-carts/"); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$cartId = json_decode($result);
```

How can I assign customer to this cart,assign address and place the order? 
Please help me

Comment: I hope this answer is help for you. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136160/70565

Comment: @SweetyMasmiya How can I assign customer to this cart?

Comment: Do you have customer already ?

Comment: @HiteshAgrawal Yes, I have customerId

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
 $guestCart    = $this->getGuestQuote($cartId);
 $customerCart = $this->getCustomerQuote($token->getCustomerId());
 $customerCart->merge($guestCart)->collectTotals()->save();
```

and below function

```
   private function getGuestQuote($cartId)
{
    try {
        $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'masked_id');
        if ($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId()) {
            return $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId());
        }
        $guestQuote = $this->quoteRepository->get($cartId);
    } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
        $this->logger->info($exception->getMessage());
        $guestQuote = '';
    }

    return $guestQuote;
} 

 private function getCustomerQuote($customerId)
{
    try {
        $customerQuote = $this->quoteRepository->getForCustomer($customerId);
    } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
        $this->logger->info($exception->getMessage());
        $store         = $this->storeManager->getStore();
        $cartId        = $this->cartManagement->createEmptyCart();
        $customerQuote = $this->quoteRepository->get($cartId);
        $customerQuote->setStore($store);
        $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
        $customerQuote->setCurrency();
        $customerQuote->assignCustomer($customer);
    }

    return $customerQuote;
}//end getCustomerQuote()
```

Comment: I want to Create order using rest API

Comment: Yes but you have to create plugin for Magento\Integration\Model\CustomerTokenService to achieve this.